# Equalivent for openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> in C#

Tags: c#, openssl

When I execute a openssl command to connect a particular server [myadda.tie.fire.glass.... dummy server name] , it gives me some output.

`openssl s_client -connect myadda.tie.fire.glass:443`

It gives me some output which contains information like

- server certificate
- issuer information

And another command which required the certificate from above command to provide me details info about the certificate.

`openssl x509 -in <Certificate_FileName.crt> -text -nout`

It gives me output as information about the certificate

- issued for server
- Validity

**I want similar kind of output using some C# classes. I am not sure how to solve this query. Can anyone help me out?**

Comment: Is your problem fetching or parsing the certificate, or both? Is this for HttpsWebRequests or SslStreams?

Comment: Both. When I tried to browse the URL through the web browser it shows Error :404. But same server when connected through openssl give desired output.

Comment: Your browser doesn't dump certificate information by default, it will show you the page you've requested (or the error) instead. e.g. if you're using Chrome, you need to go to the Security tab in Developer Tools and 'View Certificate'.

Comment: [Here's the first part](https://en.code-bude.net/2017/02/21/how-to-download-ssl-tls-certificates-in-csharp/): you want HttpWebRequest.[ServicePoint.Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.certificate) or [SslStream.RemoteCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.remotecertificate).

Answer (score 1):

Well below code help me to retrieve the required information.

```
            X509Certificate2 cert = null;
            var client = new TcpClient(host, 443);
            var certValidation = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate (object snd, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chainLocal, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            {
                //Accept every certificate, even if it's invalid
                return true;
            });

            // Create an SSL stream and takeover client's stream
            using (var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), true, certValidation))
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

                var serverCertificate = sslStream.RemoteCertificate;
                cert = new X509Certificate2(serverCertificate);

                //Convert Raw Data to Base64String
                var certBytes = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);

                var certAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(certBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.None);

            }
```

Here **vertAsString** gives me the certificate whereas **cert** gives me the other required information.